# Print message instead of error S3 policy BOTO3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am supposed to get the policy for buckets for those it exists and just a normal error statement for buckets where olicy does not exist.Used the following code to get the s3 bucket policy:

```
s3=boto3.client("s3",aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
for i in Bucket_Name:                              #Bucket_name stores the name of the buckets
     policy = s3.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=i)
     print(policy['Policy'])
```

Now,for buckets that have policy,it print hem out but for those that don't it gives out the following error,and stops further execution.
*botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchBucketPolicy) when calling the GetBucketPolicy operation: The bucket policy does not exist*

Is there a way to print some message instead of this error and continue the code execution for all other buckets?

Comment: [`try except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: added a solution, and documentation from official boto pages :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Botocore exceptions are statically defined in the botocore package. Any Boto3 clients you create will use these same statically defined exception classes. `The most common botocore exception you’ll encounter is ClientError.`(**which is the same error in your code too**) This is a general exception when an error response is provided by an AWS service to your Boto3 client’s request.* [docs for reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html#:%7E:text=Botocore%20exceptions%20are%20statically%20defined%20in%20the%20botocore%20package.&text=The%20most%20common%20botocore%20exception,to%20your%20Boto3%20client%27s%20request.).

Try like this

```
import botocore
import boto3

client = boto3.client('aws_service_name')

try:
    client.some_api_call(SomeParam='some_param')
    #your code here
    for i in Bucket_Name:
      policy = s3.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=i)
      print(policy['Policy'])

except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
    # Put your error handling logic here
    

except botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError as error:
    raise ValueError('The parameters you provided are incorrect: {}'.format(error)) #for parameter validation kind of error
```

Answer (score 2):

This code would deal with the exception:

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
for i in Bucket_Name:
    try:  # Bucket_name stores the name of the buckets
        policy = s3.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=i)
        print(policy['Policy'])
    except ClientError:
        print(f'The bucket {i} does not have a policy')
```

Comment: throws the following error: NameError: name 'ClientError' is not defined

Comment: from botocore.exceptions import ClientError